# How to use dropbox with Django on heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, dropbox

I'm fairly new to django.
So heroku doesn't support image storage so I will have to use an other container for it. I've found a lot of tutorials for using Amazon S3 but I would like to use dropbox since it's free. Is this possible?
I've found this package https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ but I still don't understand how to use it. If anybody has used it please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sign up (if you haven’t already), go to the DropBox App Console, create a new application and generate the Access Token.

Use then the [Python Dropbox SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python):

```
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('access_token')

# create file
filename = '/local_files/file.json'
dbx.files_upload(f.read(), filename, mute=True)

# read file
filename = '/dropbox_root/file.json'
f, r = dbx.files_download(filename)
print(r.content)
```

You can see the [Files on Heroku](https://medium.com/geekculture/files-on-heroku-cd09509ed285) Medium post to see the details and few other options.

Comment: Hi, do you have additionnal information regarding the fact that dropbox is moving out from tokens towards OAUTH authorizations that requires interactive user authentification ?

When the app is pushed on heroku it's not that straightforward.